# How to convert Long to Duration (import scala.concurrent.duration) in SCALA

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I  am a begginer programmer and have a very simple problem in scala, I want to convert a long var to Duration (import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration, import scala.concurrent.duration), in order to fit this code.

*listener ! PiApproximation(pi, duration = (System.currentTimeMillis - start).millis)*

Eclipse throws me the error that millis its not a member of Long, I am doing a tutorial for learning how to programme in Scala with Akka (https://github.com/fhelg/AkkaPlayGround/blob/master/PingPongApp.scala). And I think the code its correct, but i cant compile it because of that.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

PD: My apologies for the bad english! I am from spain and we are not that good at language learning :P!

Comment: The second import should be this: `import scala.concurrent.duration._`

Comment: import akka.util.duration._   as you use Akka

Answer (score 9):

Scala provides implicit [conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.concurrent.duration.Duration) which automatically/implicitly convert `Int`s and `Long`s:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> (System.currentTimeMillis - 1234567890).millis
res0: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 1394598256075 milliseconds
```